# task scheduling laravel get data from database

Tags: mysql, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, laravel-9

I'm new at this guys(Laravel) and I need to store my data collected from my DB each six hours. I thought of using laravel's task scheduling, but in the kernel where I'm supposed to create my cron job, I don't think that I can return my data as an array
I use 6 arrays each one of them in a different page.
Here is an exemple of one of them :

```
$dataGlobal = DB::select("select * from articles order by articleDate ASC");
```

PS: the code bellow is in my controller and I return the array with its view

Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
    $schedule->call(function(){
        DB::select("select * from articles order by articleDate ASC");
    })->cron('* */6 * * *');
}
```

Any ideas guys ? How can I store my data in an array where m going to use it in my pages (It's already working when I stop manually the project and relaunch it with php artisan serve)

Comment: you need to make a conosle command and add logic in that command then register this console command in kernel.php like this $schedule->command(AutomationExtraLesson::class)->everyMinute();

Comment: Can you add some details please ?

Comment: this will help you https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-cron-job-task-scheduling-tutorialexample.html

Comment: I've seen this article already, thank you tho but it didn't fully answered my question. I don't see how can I return the array where i need to store my data in it

Comment: do you solve you issue or not yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I solved my issue, I'm sharing it here if someone faced the same thing.
Laravel is a PHP's Framework, and php is a scripting language. Each time a person naviguate through my site each row is executed at that time.
By doing so, my array will always contain latest rows of my database. I don't really need a cron-job for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return data from cron job.

I think what you need is:

Create cron job that collect data each 6 hours and store it on table to your database. so you could use that data from the table you have created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).